# const difference between auto_ptr and raw pointer?

Tags: c++

I realized that when you do `const auto_ptr<X> ptr = variable`, you are still able to modify the content of the variable the auto_ptr points to. For raw pointer `const X * ptr = variable` , const prevent you from modifying it.

So what is exactly the purpose of having const in front of auto_ptr?

Comment: Not answering the question. Just making a comment. You really should use `std::unique_ptr` and/or `std::shared_ptr` rather than the deprecated (for good reason) `std::auto_ptr`. Just say no...

Comment: The "point" is that the language doesn't have special-case rules for things, regardless of whether they are semantically useful. `const` can be applied to *any type*; it's up to the programmer to decide if it is warranted for a particular circumstance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement:

```cpp
auto_ptr<X> ptr = variable;
// non-const auto_ptr object pointing to a non-const X object
// Can change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can change where the auto_ptr itself points at.
```

Is equivalent to this:

```cpp
X* ptr = variable;
// non-const pointer to a non-const X object
// Can change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can change where the pointer itself points at.
```

This statement:

```cpp
const auto_ptr<X> ptr = variable;
// const auto_ptr object pointing to a non-const X object
// Can change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can't change where the auto_ptr itself points at.
```

Is equivalent to this:

```cpp
X* const ptr = variable;
// const pointer to a non-const X object
// Can change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can't change where the pointer itself points at.
```

This statement:

```cpp
auto_ptr<const X> ptr = variable;
// non-const auto_ptr object pointing to a const X object
// Can't change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can change where the auto_ptr itself points at.
```

Is equivalent to this:

```cpp
const X * ptr = variable;
// non-const pointer to a const X object
// Can't change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can change where the pointer itself points at.
```

This statement:

```cpp
const auto_ptr<const X> ptr = variable;
// const auto_ptr object pointing to a const X object
// Can't change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can't change where the auto_ptr itself points at.
```

Is equivalent to this:

```cpp
const X* const ptr = variable;
// const pointer to a const X object
// Can't change the contents of the X object being pointed at.
// Can't change where the pointer itself points at.
```

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me other equivalent as well? Or where can I found those equivalent and explanation?

Comment: @user1701840, hope the updated answer addresses that.